# Do the Simpsons have any particular accent?

Tags: the-simpsons

I understand some of the characters have specific accents such as Fat Tony or Apu. But does the Simpson family have an accent that you could identify with a certain area in the US?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell through their caricature voices, but interesting question! I gave it an upvote.

Comment: Seeing that all 4 cast members playing the family are from different places, and that Springfield's location has been under wraps for long (and thus probably unknown from the very beginning), they might not have *one* identifiable accent (though possibly separate ones).

Comment: Compared to the rest of the family, Marge does seem to have an accent though I have no idea where it's from. On the other hand, it could simply be the "accent" of women who smoke too much.

Comment: It's the accent from Springfie]̩̲ ̧̛̟̥̺͚̗͝ḁ̕Y̴̛҉̼̟:̜̰̱̟̙͔͢͞͝ ̡̛̙̘r҉҉͚̤̤͔͈̩̤ͅe҉͖̳

Answer (score 8):

My personal opinion:

- Marge seems East Coast.  A nasslly NY thing – like she's going for a reprise of the Edith Bunker character from the 70s TV show *All in the Family*.
- Homer and Bart seem straight Midwest/Chicago to me, but dumbed-down; and Bart with the occasional SoCal vernacular.
- Lisa seems neutral; but if I had to guess I'd say East Coast boarding school.

Comment: What about maggie? No... wait